# Pandas Dtypes : float64 to 'Object' Conversion

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to understand how/why the data converts from float64 to 'Object'.

I have the following dataframe with these columns and dtypes:

```
result.dtypes

Layer Name            object
Top Depth            float64
Total Unit Weight      int64
GWT                   object
Modeling              object
Friction Angle       float64
Uni. Su Profile      float64
Min. Su              float64
Depth Datum          float64
Su Increment         float64
POP                  float64
Uni. P'p             float64
SHANSEP (on/off)      object
dtype: object


result.loc[result['Modeling']=='Undrained',['Uni. Su Profile','Min. Su']]

    Uni. Su Profile    Min. Su
3   NaN                500.0
4   500.0              NaN
5   NaN                650.0
7   NaN                NaN
12  NaN                375.0
... ... ..

result.loc[result['Modeling']=='Undrained',['Uni. Su Profile','Min. Su']].dtypes

Uni. Su Profile    NaN
Min. Su            NaN
Name: 7, dtype: object

result.loc[result['Modeling']=='Undrained',['Uni. Su Profile','Min. Su']].values
array([[  nan,  500.],
   [ 500.,   nan],
   [  nan,  650.],.....
```

Now I want to erase rows with empty data such as row 7. I thought of using all() but it doesnt behave as expected. I expected row 7 to be False.

```
result.loc[result['Modeling']=='Undrained',['Uni. Su Profile','Min. Su']].all(axis=1)

3      True
4      True
5      True
7      True
12     True
```

When I check on the dtypes for row 7 it gives the following:

```
result.loc[7,['Uni. Su Profile','Min. Su']]

Uni. Su Profile    NaN
Min. Su            NaN
Name: 7, dtype: object
```

Did the data change from float64 to 'Object' or what is hapenning?

Thanks,

Comment: I cannot replicate . . . what is returned when you do `result.loc[7,['Uni. Su Profile','Min. Su']].values`

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have edited the comment. It gives a numpy.ndarray